# Automating Codeship notifications to individual people in Slack

Tags: slack, codeship

Currently, we have Codeship (Basic) set up to send failures to a Slack channel. However, I've found that most people don't proactively look there (or in Codeship's UI) and see that their latest commit failed to pass (because, ahem, developers assume their code is perfect??). In the Slack message is the GitHub committer name, which, of course, doesn't match their Slack account.

There's seemingly no good way of mapping that name to an individual user who could either get the notification directly or at least be @ notified automatically in the our Codeship failures channel. Anyone have any good mechanisms for better automating the Codeship to individual user getting a Slack notification? One of the Github email addresses does match an email address in Slack, but I don't know how much that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: While this is a good question and a valid problem you are experiencing, this question might be a little too vague to get any attention. You might need to come up with your own data structure that contains a mapping between Slack username & GitHub username, and handle the 'matching' functionality in your actual code. If you give us a starting example with what you've tried, the community can try to help you better.

Comment: I have no code -- or place to put code -- in the middle.  There's a built-in integration from Codeship to Slack (via a webhook). Presumably, some solution would allow me to put in code to map the usernames somewhere (or base it off of email address), but I'm trying to figure out how others have inserted something in the middle here to do this (or if Codeship themselves have thought about this problem).